PKCS11 cannot Initialize: called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Pkcs11(GeneralError)
I try to open new session to softhsm2.
let pkcs11 =  Pkcs11::new(
        env::var("PKCS11_SOFTHSM2_MODULE")
            .unwrap_or_else(|_| "/usr/lib/softhsm/libsofthsm2.so".to_string()),
    )
    .unwrap();
 
    // initialize the library
pkcs11.initialize(CInitializeArgs::OsThreads).unwrap();

It got panic when meet the line pkcs11.initialize.... What is wrong here?
I tried with sudo pkcs11-tool --module /usr/lib/softhsm/libsofthsm2.so  --list-slot, it is fine.
Besides, there was one time Rust code works with that line but cannot return existing slots.

Please post a Minimal Reproducible Example. At the very least, post the panic message and backtrace.

The problem is the service cannot open the tokens folder, because it cannot check the configuration file of softhsm2 to know token.dir
I check the configuration file of softhsm2 using cat and detect the permission error. So it needs to be granted permission, everyone should be able to access /etc/softhsm2.conf.
and also allow the access to /var/lib/softhsm/tokens too.
